# Hibernate: org.hibernate.TransactionException.

Tags: hibernate, exception

The issue with the following function is

> it throws `TransactionException` if their are no users in database,  when I rollback transaction in the
>   catch block.
>
> If I remove rollbackstatement it throws the `DataNotFoundException` as expected.

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    List<T> entityList= null;
    Transaction tr = sessionUtil.getSession().getTransaction();
    try {
          tr.begin();
          entityList= sessionUtil.getSession()
                     .createQuery("from "+type.getSimpleName()).list();
          tr.commit();
         if(entityList.isEmpty())
            throw new DataNotFoundException("404", "No "+type.getSimpleName()+"'s present ");

        } catch ( RuntimeException e) {
       // tr.rollback();
        throw new EvaluateException(e);
    }

    return entityList;
}
```

Please help. thank you

Comment: That's probably because `DataNotFoundException` is a `RuntimeException`, so once you are in the catch block the transaction had already been commited (`tr.commit()`). Also, you should mark your transaction as `readonly`

Comment: well I found the issue. 
Actually the `DataNotFoundException` is thrown after committing the transaction. so when it is called, transaction is already committed and when exception is thrown, their is no transaction to rollback.

So two solutions.
1) Either remove the rollback, Coz transaction is committed always either their are users or no users
2) Throw the exception inside the transaction so it never completes, incase their are no Users. personally I find it more reasonable.

I would like your suggestions also. thank you